# Why does my index go to zero in r

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

```
data = matrix(1:12, 3,4)
n=ncol(data)
m=nrow(data)

for (i in 1:m){
  for (j in 1:n-1){
    missindex = sample(1:n,j)
    temp <- data[,-missindex]
    distances <- dist(temp)[1:m-1]
    similarity <- 1-distances/max(distances)
    order_indexes <- order(similarity,decreasing = T)
    similarity_order <- similarity[order_indexes]
    for (k in 1:m-1){
      weights <- similarity_order[1:k]/sum(similarity_order[1:k])
      imputedata <- crossprod(data[order_indexes[1:k]+1,missindex], weights)
      MAE <- mean(abs(imputedata-data[i,missindex]))
      RMSE <- sqrt(mean((imputedata - data[i,missindex])^2))
      MAPE <- mean(abs((imputedata-data[i,missindex])/data[i,missindex]))
    }
  }
}
```

it gives me the following error:

> Error in crossprod(data[order_indexes[1:k] + 1, missindex], weights) : 
>     non-conformable arguments

When I check k is 0, but in my code k is from 1 to m-1.

Comment: Use `j in 1:(n-1)` in the inner loop, i.e. put parentheses around the `n-1`. Read the `R intro` manual.

Comment: @Bhas Not just that loop.  Also in the loop on `k`.

Comment: To the OP, this is a precedence problem, which has many duplicates.

Comment: @ Mathew Lundberg.  Correct. I hadn't seen that one because I didn't look further.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338980/canonical-question-for-r-gotcha-colon-operator-takes-higher-precedence-than-ari

Comment: Great! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

`1:n-1` is not 1,...,n-1, but rather 0,...,n-1 because `:` has higher precedence than `+`.

Instead of `1:n-1` here, use `seq(n-1)` or `1:(n-1)`.